# Как вызвать обработчик PropertyChanged из другого потока

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, async-await

Из ViewModel оформлена подписка на события класса C1.
В классе C1 запущен асинхронный метод, в процессе работы которого генерируются события. Обработчик изменяет свойство в ViewModel:

```
private void onBeginLoadProducts()
{
    StatusMsg = "Ожидание ответа";
}

private void onEndLoadProducts()
{
    StatusMsg = "Ответ получен";
}
```

....

```
public string StatusMsg
{
    get
    {
        return this.statusMsg;
    }

    private set
    {
        this.statusMsg = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StatusMsg"));
    }
}
```

На вызове PropertyChanged происходит ошибка:

```
System.Exception: "Приложение обратилось к интерфейсу, относящемуся к другому потоку. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))"
```

К свойству StatusMsg есть привязка(x:Bind) из UI. Я знаю, что обращаться к UI элементам можно только из главного потока, но каким образом решить данную задачу? Объект который генерирует событие, выполняет асинхронный метод, когда закончит неизвестно. А иметь контроль состоянии о выполнении нужно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пробросьте в VM диспетчер UI-потока, например, параметром конструктора или получите его внутри VM:

```
var dispatcher = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;
```

затем, при необходимости запуска кода в UI-потоке, используйте его:

```
await dispatcher.RunAsync(
    Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
    () => StatusMsg = "Ожидание ответа"); // onBeginLoadProducts);
```

Comment: А че так сложно то? App.Current.Dispatcher же есть. Ну или Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher, который равен нужному, если программист не мудрит свой Dispatcher

Comment: @vitidev в UWP?

Answer (score 1):

Код после корректировок:

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
private CoreDispatcher dispatcher = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher;

private async void OnBeginLoadProducts()
{
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => StatusMsg = "Запрос на получение продуктов");
}
```